# openflow: How to get the ingress port on packet reception?

Tags: opendaylight

I am writing a Java ODL application. I am following the general pattern of L2-Switch. I have a PacketIn dispatcher where I would like to know the port of connected switch where a packet was received. How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `in_port` like this :

```
 @Override
 public void onPacketReceived(PacketReceived packetReceived) {
        Match match = packetReceived.getMatch();
        String inPort = match.getInPort().getValue();
}
```

Supposing that this method belongs to a class you have created implementing the `PacketProcessingListener`:

```
public class PacketProcessing implements PacketProcessingListener{
    ...
}
```

Comment: What is packetReceived.getIngress()  ? Thanks.

Comment: @LostInTheFrequencyDomain where did you see that?